# Should I run Django "makemigrations" against all of my apps?

Tags: django, django-models

I've just upgraded my project to Django 1.8.4.  I've never used migrations in this project before.  I discovered that I had to explicitly run the "makemigrations" command against four of my apps since they contained foreign keys to the auth_user table.  Do I need to run the makemigrations command against my other six applications?  The reason I ask is because the [documents](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#adding-migrations-to-apps) say,

> If your app already has models and database tables, and doesn’t have migrations yet (for example, you created it against a previous Django version), you’ll need to convert it to use migrations"

However, when I ran the command against my "home" app, I received this message:

```
No changes detected in app 'home'
```

When converting a project to Django 1.8, should you run the makemigrations command against *all* of your apps and then run "migrate --fake-initial" if the actual database tables already exist?

Thanks.

Comment: I have updated my answer after suffering for a lot of hours ... It is essential to migrate all the applications **simultaneously** if django cannot do it with the relevant command.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update:** Make sure that the `migrations` folder contains an `__init__.py`.

---

Indeed, there are many times, I have to delete and recreate my development database.

During this procedure, I have encountered the same issue especially after upgrading to `Django 1.8.* / 1.9.*`.

In my script, after deleting the contents of my migrations folders, I am running `makemigrations` in all my applications <del>separately</del> [simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36153748/django-1-9-makemigrations-no-changes-detected/36972913#36972913).

`./manage.py makemigrations <myapp1> <myapp2> ... <myappN>`

Before that, I backup all my data:

```
./manage.py dumpdata --exclude auth.permission --exclude contenttypes --exclude admin.LogEntry --indent 2 > db.json
```

Comment: I'm afraid of migrations.  Specifically, I'm afraid I'll get into a situation in which migrations won't run and I won't be able to update the migration files so they will.  If I ever reach that point, can I assume I'll be able to do as you described and delete all the migration files in my "migrations" directories, run "makemigrations" on each app, and essentially start over?  Thanks.

Comment: @Robert Sometimes migrations make me feel that their complicated structure will leave me hanging in front of a situation I am unable to cope with. Some other times, they leave me speechless of their capabilities which saved me from destroying the database. At the bottom line -however- all that counts, are the data. I really enjoy, deleting the database and restoring it automatically, just to avoid the fuss of debugging migrations. Somewhere there lies the secret that makes our relationship balanced. I have updated my answer!